# I am trying this JSP program but i am getting HTML 500 error(page not found)

Tags: html, xml, jsp, jstl

Here is my program files.
when i divide 20 by 5 i get answer 4 Okay. Correct!
But when i divide 20 by 0 i doesn't get Aspected Output.
Instead i get Page cannot be displayed error HTML 500 Internal server error.

Using NetBeans 8.2 and Internet Explorer.
index.html

```
<form action="process.jsp">
No1:<input type="text" name="n1" /><br/><br/>
No2:<input type="text" name="n2" /><br/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="divide"/></form>
```

process.jsp

```
<%@page errorPage="error.jsp" %>
<%

String num1=request.getParameter("n1");
String num2=request.getParameter("n2");

int a=Integer.parseInt(num1);
int b=Integer.parseInt(num2);
int c=a/b;
out.print("division of numbers is: "+c);

%>
```

error.jsp

```
<%@page isErrorPage="true" %>
<html>  
    <body>  
        An unexpected exception was encountered.  
        The admin monkeys are looking into the issue.  
        <br><br>  
        Exception is : <%= exception %>  
    </body>  
</html>
```

Comment: what is the result of "20 / 0"?

Comment: ArithmaticException divided by Zero.

Comment: No worries i got the solution. problem was with Internet Explorer, it worked in chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with Internet Explorer with chrome it worked.